# What is the origin of the trope of enslaved wizards/witches?

Tags: history-of, magic, trope

I have been reading *The Wheel of Time* books, and found the Seanchan Damanes to be very similar to *The Tethered Mage* books, where magic is rare and strictly controlled (even with minders that use devices to control the magic). I also saw a very similar control of magic in *The Fifth Season* where Guardians controlled the Orogenes' use of magic.

Is there a clear origin to this trope of strictly controlled magic (typically wielded by women) and a non-magic class that controls the wizards/witches?

Comment: Are you asking just about cases where the magic is under control of the source, but their actions are compelled, or also cases where the source is used essentially as a battery, but the use of the magic is performed by someone else?

Comment: I hadn't come across the second case before. I was asking here specifically about cases where "magic is under control of the source, but their actions are compelled", but would be interested in both now that I know more!

Comment: The first instance of the latter that I can think of offhand is probably Norton's *Witch World* (1963) where after they are married Jaelithe basically loses her ability to do magic except that she can assist Tregare's magic.

Comment: Posting this question on Reddit led me to the "oppressed magic" trope which has a lot written on it and then https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuperHumanTrafficking which lists Hercules as a plausible origin of this trope.